# Liberty Service created by Prunsrv.exe stops automatically in Windows Server 2019

Tags: services, windows-server-2019

I have created a server in Websphere Liberty on Windows Server 2019 and registered a service for it too. When I start the service, the status changes to **Running**, but after a few seconds the status disappears (i.e. the service stops). However, the server bound with the service is actually running in the background.

The Liberty Server functions as expected and can be stopped through command line without any issue, the only problem is that the status of the service is shown incorrectly in services.msc. This leads me to believe that the service wrapper shipped with Liberty(Prunsrv.exe) isn't compatible with Windows Server 2019 as I had not faced this issue on Windows Server 2008/2012/2106.

Is there anything specific that has to be done to make it work on Windows Server 2019? Any suggestions/points would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ronan

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.  I tried different service wrappers, NSSM and WinSW.  After some trial and error, I noticed that the service would stop running on my system after approximately 39 seconds.  I performed the same command, server.bat start yourServer, from the command window.  I noticed that the time from the start to the time that the batch file completes and returns to a command prompt was about 39 seconds.

WinSW logs to event viewer.  I checked the messages and noticed that WinSW logged that the process completed successfully with an exit code of 0.

So I changed the way the server is started and run.  I changed the command from server.bat start yourServer to server.bat run yourServer.  This worked.  I can now start and stop the server.

In my case, I am using WinSW.  An XML file must be configured for WinSW.  I used server.bat with starting arguments for run and yourServer for starting the service.  I used stop arguments of stop and yourServer for stopping the service.

The WinSW documentation is okay at getting you going.

I don't know your exact situation so I cannot provide examples using your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, this issue was fixed in Liberty profile 19.0.0.3. Apparently, this issue was caused due to Windows update​ 1809. The same can be fixed by either upgrading the Server runtime or rolling back the mentioned upgrade or by making the following change in server.bat https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/commit/aa5098244e0e9260893319c91a70e094ef2e8f26#diff-d26ac0111691649335e5f73e54dc0819